# How to have an ActiveItem and Items together in one view

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a view that contains a ActiveItem content control and Items TabControl as given below.

```
<UserControl x:Class="HotelReservation.Main.Views.RoomBands.RoomBandMainView"

    ...  
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        ...  
        <Border Grid.Column="0" >
            <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" />
        </Border>

        <GridSplitter Width="5" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />

        <Border Grid.Column="2"  >
            <TabControl x:Name="Items" Margin="5" />
        </Border>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I don't know how to set the ActiveItem in the view model for the above view. At any time, there will be a ActiveItem for Content Control, and Items for TabControl. In the viewmodel, now I cannot just call ActivateItem. How do I solve this scenario.

Comment: For me, it's unclear what you're trying to achieve. You can simply bind your `ContentControl` to a viewmodel property. Please describe your issue more precisely.

Comment: @dymanoid Yes that's what I did. I figured out a little late that ActiveItem and Items are to be bound to the ViewModel with that properties. I guess that's what you are trying to say. Thanks

Comment: can you show what your viewmodel is inheriting and then how is your shellviewmodel defined...

Comment: @mvermef I have resolved this issue. Please look my previous comment. I think there is nothing special about ActiveItem and Items property. Now I have them as properties in my view model and it works correctly. Thanks